# Maximum number of orders can hold by Magento in its lifetime

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

By default, the magento order increment id is 9 digits something like #000000034 and wanted to know what if the order increment id reaches #999999999. So I have edited the table eav_entity_store, updated the increment_last_id value as 999999999 and placed two orders. I got the new increment Ids as 11000000000 and 11000000001. So its clear for me that the order is not stopping at 999999999 and its still growing. However I am not sure about the maximum limit.

Do anyone having any idea on what will be the maximum number of orders can a Magento website hold in its lifetime, since our current store can be filled up with thousands of orders everyday and not sure if it reaches any maximum limit?

Comment: just curious to know how many orders are there in backend currently ?

Comment: hi @baby-in-magento, its fresh grocery shop actually and getting around 400 orders everyday without any marketing. Hopefully to reach more numbers soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, to be honest this is more like a MySQL question than a Magento question. As of M2 2.1.9+ the length of `increment_id` is actually 32 length and of `varchar` type which means it can also use characters if numbers run out (which is very unlikely) and the `entity_id` is length of 10 and type `INT`.

Length `INT(9)` means that no matter what, you want the integer to be shown at most with 9 digits. So if you store an integer that's larger than 9 digits, it will only be displayed as if it had 9 digits, but its actual value will be stored.

So based on the above and in theory Magento should still be able to take orders.

References

[Size of column of int(11) in mysql in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes)

Comment: hi @andré-ferraz,  thanks for your explanation and it seems magento can take orders as much as we want. Thats really great!